# Refactoring a project generated from Petapoco

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, refactoring, petapoco

I'm creating a C# Win Forms app using PetaPoco as micro ORM. I want to refactor the generated classes to make them easily testable and mockable.
When I started to write the Unit Test I get stuck with Mock because I do not use interfaces, but I dont know how to integrate the interfaces with the current classes.

This are the classes

```
public partial class League : FutbolDB.Record<League>
{
    public int? id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? CantTeams { get; set; }
}

public partial class Team : FutbolDB.Record<Team>
{
    public int? id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    private int? LeagueId { get; set; }
}
```

Then I extend this classes

```
public partial class Team : FutbolDB.Record<Team>
{
    private League _league; 

    public Team() {}

    public Team(string name, League league)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            throw new ArgumentException("The name cannot be empty or null");
        if (league == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("The League cannot be null");
        Name = name;
        League = league;
    }

    [Ignore]
    public League League
    {
        get { return _league ?? League.GetById(LeagueId); }
        set {
            _league = value;
            LeagueId = _league?.id;
        }
    }
```

Now when I Unit Test

```
    //this runs fine
    [TestMethod()] 
    public void EqualsTest()
    {
        Mock<League> mockLeague = new Mock<League>();

        var t1 = new Team("team",mockLeague.Object);
        var t2 = new Team("Team", mockLeague.Object);

        t1.id = 1;
        t2.id = 1;

        Assert.IsTrue(t1.Equals(t1));
        Assert.IsFalse(t1.Equals(null));
        Assert.IsTrue(t1.Equals(t2));
    }
```

The problem is when I try to Stub the method CantTeams from League, that without interfaces Mock throws and error.

```
    public TeamTests()
    {
        List<Team> teams = new List<Team>();
        teams.Add(new Team("barca", mockLeague.Object));
        teams.Add(new Team("atletico", mockLeague.Object));
        teams.Add(new Team("madrid", mockLeague.Object));

        // Error stubbing this method from a concrete class
        mockLeague.Setup(x => x.CantTeams).Returns(teams.Count);
    }
```

Unit testing, Mock and Patterns are new to me and I'm currently trying to learn them. Thanks in advance

Comment: You are trying to write unit tests for you rmodels that say 'when i create a model with id 1 then id is 1'. While it is noble of you, this is basically testing the .net framework memory properties (or even that of CLR). It is the same as testing `var a = 42; Assert.AreEqual(42,a);`. Certainly that test will always pass, but is it useful?

The tests exist to test the `logic` of the code. Declaring a property is not logic. Nevertheless, if you do want to test the models, use reflection (see next comment)

Comment: `Assert.AreEqual(typeof(int?), typeof(League).GetProperty("id", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).PropertyType));`

Comment: thanks for your answer, now I'm testing only for that the object is not null and that it equals the other.

Comment: then just use my sample above?

Comment: I see why is irrelevant to test  than an object is equal to itself so i removed it. Right now i don't need to check for the ID nor use Reflection. Just keeping it simple. Thanks but I'm just learning, easy steps now.